# First element in object is undefined using += operator

Tags: javascript, variables, object, undefined, element

I have a problem to use the operator += in an object.
Because i have to change the variable dynamically i use an object as variable.
But if i use the += operator the first element in the output always gets undefined. I think thats because the object is initialized empty.

What is the best solution to prevent to output that element ?

Here goes my example code:

```
var dynamicVariable = {};
var group = "apples";

for(var i = 1; i<5; i++)
{
 dynamicVariable[group] += " Apple" + i + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("fruits").innerHTML = dynamicVariable[group];
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs4czxkt/)

Comment: Just first set `dynamicVariable[group] = ""`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because `dynamicVariable[group]` has the value `undefined` before you start appending to it. `undefined + " Apple1"` is `"undefined Apple1"`.

You need to initialize it to an empty string first:

```
dynamicVariable[group] = "";
for(var i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    dynamicVariable[group] += " Apple" + i + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Adding to your answer, you need to say that the value is `undefined` and when you use `+=` it will convert it to a string. Converting `undefined` to string returns `'undefined'`.